# App trava ao dar create no Datamodule

Tags: android, delphi, sqlite

Estou criando uma aplicação Android em delphiXE7 e tudo funciona até que eu vou criar dinamicamente o datamodule. Aí ele trava e não volta mais.

```
procedure TForm1.Btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var M:TModalResult;
begin
Application.CreateForm(TDataModule1, DataModule1);
end;
```

eu tive que fazer este create dinamico porque antes, quando ele criava automaticamente o aplicativo só ficava com uma tela preta e não iniciava.

Lembrando que nem chega a executar esse codigo no BeforeConnection do TFDConnection;

```
{$IF DEFINED (IOS) || (ANDROID)}
DataModule1.Conn1.Params.Values['DriverID'] := 'SQLite';
try
DataModule2.Conn1.Params.Values['Database']:= TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Banco002.SQLite');
DataModule2.Conn1.Connected := True;
      except on E: Exception do
      begin
        raise Exception.Create('Erro de conexão com o banco de dados!');
      end;
{$ENDIF}
```

Alguem ja teve ete problema?
Uso delphi Xe7, sqlite, Android 4.2 Smartphone Samsung DUOS e SDK atualizada.

Comment: Pq você não coloca o DataModule no autocreate do projeto e conecta no banco pelo Create do DataModule. Uma pergunta, essa extensão do SQLLite ta certa?... não seria Banco002.db

Comment: Eu salvei com a extensão SQLLite para difenciar de versoes antigas que eu estava usando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui identificar o problema.
Enquanto testava o APP em designtime, eu esqueci uma tabela aberta e, como o caminho mobile do banco era diferente, então o aplicativo travava, pois estava procurando o banco ates do método

```
{$IF DEFINED (IOS) || (ANDROID)}
DataModule1.Conn1.Params.Values['DriverID'] := 'SQLite';
try
DataModule2.Conn1.Params.Values['Database']:= TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'Banco002.SQLite');
DataModule2.Conn1.Connected := True;
      except on E: Exception do
      begin
        raise Exception.Create('Erro de conexão com o banco de dados!');
      end;
{$ENDIF}
```